HTML website displays fonts differently on iOS and Web
I've created a website, however the website displays the font incorrectly on mobile devices for some reason, defaulting to Arial on Safari and Google browsers despite showing correctly on Edge on Windows 10.


@font-face {
  font-family: 'OPTICaslonFive';
  src: url('../OPTICaslonFive.otf') format('opentype'), url('../OPTICaslonFive.woff') format('woff');
}

h1,
h4 {
  font-family: 'OPTICaslonFive', Arial, sans-serif !important;
}



I don't understand what could be causing the disparity? How can I fix this?

The use of Arial on iOS suggests that the font OPTICaslonFive isn't available. Are you certain that (a) the OTF or WOFF formats are supported by the iOS browsers, and (b) that the relative path points to where you think it does on the iOS browsers?

A time ago, I had a similar problem. My font was loading fine on the localhost server but was not working on the online web server. I figured that the problem was in the Naming. My font file name case doesn't match the real file name located in the storage/server. so I fixed it by naming the font file name in lowercase in both storage and inside the code. The local host was not case-sensitive, so a different case worked out there. But didn't work online. Hope this might help you!

Please check your dev tools network tab for font entries. Most likely you see a locally installed version on windows and the path/URL is incorrect. So mobile browsers can't find them. Your path needs to be relative to the final output directory of you css file.
